# MYSQL - Turkish character

Tags: mysql

I retrieve datas from mysql

This is normally which i have in db

This is normally i have in db

```
Seçimler, Şirketler ve Siyasi Partiler
```

it prints

```
Se�imler, ?irketler ve Siyasi Partiler
```

I use sql yog and change some preferences in my db

i set Charset to UTF8 and Collation is utf8_turkish_ci

but still retrieve datas like that

```
Se�imler, ?irketler ve Siyasi Partiler
```

why? What's the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting HTML foreign characters from MySQL tables to utf-8 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003242/converting-html-foreign-characters-from-mysql-tables-to-utf-8-characters)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this problem sounds like you've missed to specify a character encoding somewhere. to solve this, simply make sure you've set character encoding to **utf-8 everywere** (it doesn't actually need to be utf-8, just *the same* everywhere - but if you've messed up something and need to change some places anyway, i'd strongly recommend using utf-8):

- tell MySQL to use utf-8. to do this, add this to your my.cnf:

  > ```
  > collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
  > character_set_server = utf8
  > ```
- before interacting with mysql, send this two querys:

  > ```
  > SET NAMES 'utf8';
  > CHARSET 'utf8';
  > ```

  or, alternatively, let php do this afteropening the connection:

  > ```
  > mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
  > ```
- set UTF-8 as the default charset for your database

  > ```
  > CREATE DATABASE `my_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
  > ```
- do the same for tables:

  > ```
  > CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  >   -- ...
  > ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  > ```
- assuming the client is a browser, serve your content as utf-8 and the the correct header:

  > ```
  > header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  > ```

  to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  > ```
- and, last but not least, tell the browser to submit forms using utf-8

  > ```
  > <form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
  > ```

Comment: I really suprised with MYSQL, because all features was set to UTF8 . Now , problem is solved.NAMES are  set to utf8 .

Comment: SET NAMES and CHARSET queries solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You need to mention `Charset to UTF8` in your selection query too.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
CHARSET 'utf8';
```

Answer (score 1):

What made the difference for me was to add these lines:

> collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
>
> character_set_server = utf8

to my.ini file (at the end of the document) I have tried everything else but they all failed until I made this change. It's really been a great help. Thanks oezi.

Answer (score 0):

I added
`$this->db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` 
in connection
and added
charset utf8 to my procedure parameters

Sample

```
PROCEDURE `up_users`(IN `lid` INT, IN `lfirstname` VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8, IN `llastname` VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8, IN `lstatus` VARCHAR(1) CHARSET utf8, IN `lpassword` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8)
```