# Charset=utf8 not working in my PHP page

Tags: php, html, css, utf-8, character-encoding

I got a problem with my character encoding. Whenever I load a page in the browser, It shows like this:
[image]

So I need to manually configure it by the browser. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sounds like you don't serve your content as utf-8. do this by setting the correct header:

> ```
> header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
> ```

in addition to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> ```

note that, depending on where the text comes from, you might have to check some other things too (database-connection, source-file-encoding, ...) - i've listed a lot of them in [one of my answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444230/288773).

Comment: With HTML5 it is enough to write `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by kraikkonen85 in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-set-charset.php#101165):

> Besides setting `mysql_set_charset` and adding `utf8` setting metadata
>   to html, another important but "unpredictable" reason is the encoding
>   type of your PHP editor when saving. For example, if you save the php
>   file other than encodings such as "`unicode`" or "`ANSI`", as i
>   experienced, you may notice weird chars like squares, question marks
>   etc.
>
> To make sure, try "save as" method to see explictly that your php file
>   is being saved as `utf8`.

it may be because your content might not  utf-8 you can set utf-s by setting the header and meta

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```