# Laravel issue with: language character encoding

Tags: encoding

Privjet!

I don't understand for what reason I am not getting displayed the non ASCII language characters like say, "ç, ñ, я " for my different languages.

The text in question is hardcoded, it is not served from a DB.

I have seen identical questions here

[Charset=utf8 not working in my PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460349/charset-utf8-not-working-in-my-php-page)

I have seen that I should write this:

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But where the heck does that go? I cant write it like that, the browser just mirrors the words and displays them as plain text, no parsing.

My encoding for the frontpage says this:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
```

which is supposed to be Unicode.

I tried to test my page in validator.w3.org and it went:

Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 60 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

Line 60 actuallly has the word Español (Spanish) with that weird n.

Any hint?

thank you

best regards

Comment: You need to make sure that you're actually sending UTF8.  That completely depends on how you're serving responses.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to figure out what's wrong.  You need to learn how text encoding works.

Comment: You're sending text in a non-UTF8 encoding.  You need to fix your code or files to send UTF8 bytes.