# cannot display trademark symbol in mysql to html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a starter in php/mySQL, and I am currently facing a problem to display symbol such as ® onto my html.  The symbol is stored in a table which can display properly when viewed from phpmyadmin, but when I use php to retrieve the table content, it does not display the symbol but instead displaying a symbol of a diamond with a ? inside it.  I have set the html page to utf-8 and my table to utf8_general_ci but no luck from those.

The symbol is able to display correctly when I put straight to html or even store in php variable.

The query I used to get the content is

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo ($row["symbol"]);

}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: When you say you set the HTML page to utf-8 did you set the encoding of the file and/or <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Charset=utf8 not working in my PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460349/charset-utf8-not-working-in-my-php-page)

Comment: How do you set the encoding and have you verified via the response headers that it is being served as utf8?

Comment: While these other suggestions should 'fix' the cause of the issue. After you change your SQL charset.  You need to delete the bad character and type it again directly into the row.  I used to have those little diamond question marks and I had to delete that character from the value stored in SQL, type it in again from the keyboard, and re-save the row.

Comment: I have set <meta charset="utf-8"> in the head

Comment: The retyping of the symbol was no luck, thanks tho aidan

Answer (score 1):

You can use html character entities instead of direct symbol

Do not use

> ®

Try it

```
&reg;
```

Answer (score 1):

These types of encoding issues can get complex when dealing with different character sets. In these cases, just changing the collation will not fix the problem, you need to change the `CHARSET`. Only after changing the `CHARSET` should you worry about the collation (they are not the same thing).

**Just to be safe, export your database/table before altering it.**

I would begin, by converting the table to `utf8` since it is now the standard.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

By doing this, it will also change the `CHARSET` of the table and columns to utf8, but you may still need to manually change the collation of the columns to `utf8_general_ci` (seems like you have already done that).

In the event you want to change the default character set (for new columns)...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

**EDIT :**
If changing the `CHARSET` in the database doesn't work, you can try setting it on the PHP side. Just add this after your connection.

**mysql**

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

**mysqli**

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

**PDO**

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"
```

Here is some helpful documentation:

[10.1 Character Set Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html)
[10.1.12 Column Character Set Conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html)
[10.1.13.1 Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Comment: Thanks EternalHour, I have converted the character of table to utf8 as you suggested, still displaying a diamond with ? inside it

Comment: @HSL808 - I've added something else to try.

Comment: The $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); Is what ended up working for me. My table is also converted and the charset of the field as well  as I tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the trademark, copyright or other symbols into/out database via an *HTMLEntity*

The `htmlentities()` function converts characters to HTML entities.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

® Registered Trademark `&#174;`

™ Trademark Symbol: `&#153;`

Other useful information and symbols can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: This has nothing to do with why the charset fails to output symbols when retrieving a MySQL Query when the symbol is fine inside the DB.