# MySQL does not work fine with UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I added this rows to my-default file, restarted server, recreated schema, table and data in the tables, but my cyrillic data still looks like '????'.
Now I have a new user and such config, but utf8 still does not work.

```
[mysqld]
init-connect=SET NAMES utf8
character-set-server=utf8
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqladmin]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlcheck]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlimport]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlshow]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8
#end
```

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790757/cannot-display-trademark-symbol-in-mysql-to-html). If it helps let me know and I will post an answer.

Comment: my-default is just a sample.  my.cnf (or my.ini) is the file that is used unless you modify the arguments to `mysqld`.

Comment: Rick, thank you!! But it still does not work. I can not believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced my.cnf by the default my.cnf, added

```
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

for the DB and all tables.

Now it is works fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do the trick. You need to perform a small query directly before you do `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. In my db-class it looks like this, which is to be adapted to your needs. `$charset` needs to be "utf8"

```
$db->query('SET CHARACTER SET "' . $charset . '";');
$result = $db->query($query);
```

I call the function like this

```
$result = $ddlab->db->db($sql,'utf8');
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But sorry for stupid question: what I need to do from mysql console? Cause you queries looks like not pure mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

`init-connect=SET NAMES utf8`

That command is important.  However, when you connect as `root` (or other `SUPER` user), that command is skipped.

Also, you need to make sure that the bytes in your client are utf8.

And the display is utf8.

If you are using the mysql commandline tool:
The command "chcp" controls the "code page". chcp 65001 provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed, too.
To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console "

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

**Edit 2**

Go into Workbench (which you used for INSERTing the text?) and do `SELECT HEX('Ремонтные');`  This should give a clue of the character set in Workbench.  utf8 will say `D0A0D0B5D0BCD0BED0BDD182D0BDD18BD0B5` (note the Dxyy pattern); cp866 will say `90A5ACAEADE2ADEBA5` (note: high bit on).  Aha!  And latin1 will say `3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F`.  Look familiar?????  Hint:  I am pointing finger at Workbench, or your use of it.

Comment: Let's verify what is in the table.  `Please do SELECT HEX(column) ...` to display some field that is coming out "????".  Perhaps the data was mangled as it was _stored_, rather than as it was _read_.

Comment: '3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F203F3F3F3F3F3F'

Comment: Bad news.  "3F" is "?".  The `INSERT`s did not have `SET NAMES` set correctly (or some other problem).  Please edit your Question to lay out the details of the INSERT -- including my.cnf settings, connection, SET NAMES (if used), source of data (need to get a feel for what byte encoding was used), etc.

Comment: Also, please provide (in the Edit), `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rn5wrCxS - config. http://pastebin.com/msuZ4HsV table, etc. Best wishes to California! You are great man! https://www.facebook.com/arthur.kharkivskiy I'll glad you to be my friend (not for SQL questions:-))

Comment: OK, nothing obviously wrong in CREATE TABLE or my.cnf.  Let's see the insert steps.  (Yes, I'm in California -- Silicon Valley.)  Any change you are using cp1251 or cp866 or 8859-5?  Those have (I think) Cyrillic characters; but they are different than utf8.

Comment: proc. body + insert http://pastebin.com/ac5rd0r2 I am not using cp1251 or cp866 or 8859-5, but not sure cause of Workbench.

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE insertCategory;` -- that will show the character set and the "security invoker/definer" that are associated with the procedure.

Comment: 'insertCategory', 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION', 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertCategory`(IN request_categoryParentId INT,\n    IN request_category         VARCHAR(128),\n    IN request_categoryPicture  VARCHAR(512))\nBEGIN\n    INSERT INTO Category (category, categoryParentId, categoryPicture)\n    VALUES (request_category, request_categoryParentId, request_categoryPicture);\nEND', 'utf8', 'utf8_general_ci', 'latin1_swedish_ci'. 'latin1_swedish_ci' - hm...

Comment: What happens if you do the INSERT inside Workbench?  That is, avoid the PROCEDURE.  (I don't yet see what caused the problem.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73655/discussion-between-arthur-kharkivskiy-and-rick-james).