# Adobe Brackets UTF-8 character errors?

Tags: php, utf-8, adobe-brackets

When I use **Notepad++** I'll save files in "UTF-8 with BOM" to avoid character displays issues like this. But **Adobe Brackets** only offers "UTF-8" encoding. I enjoy this program but this seems like a really BASIC oversight in not being able to process special characters like ♥ but some more common. Here's an example of what I'm referring to which should be a fancy single-quote:

[image]

If I go into **Notepad++** and save it "with BOM" it will display fine.

Does anyone understand why this happens and how to remedy it? How could they make such a great application and overlook this. Am I missing something really simple? *This happens with PHP and JavaScript files.*

Comment: Since you are actually asking about character encoding of HTML with PHP used to set the header, an already-existing answer would be: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10460368/711717

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found a resolution by adding this in **HTML**

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

or this in **PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```