# URL and Title with Foreign Characters

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, slug

Someone can add articles on my ASPX webpage.

For example they type in something like this as Title:

```
Öçöçü
```

This is saved in the database as:

```
Öçöçü
```

But when I need to read it from the database to create an url for it, then I read it in this format:

```
Ococu
```

So I send people to read the article to this url: `www.test.com/ococu` and the `Ococu` is the Querystring.

I need to retrieve the content of this article with the title `Öçöçü`, but I can't do something like

`SELECT * FROM Article WHERE Title = Ococu` (Ococu = querystring), because it has been saved to the database as `Öçöçü`

What can I do to solve this? I need to execute that Query but that is not possible because the querystring doesn't contain the foreign characters which are saved in the database.

Or should I create two attributes in the database? One for the `Title` and the other for the `URL`? So I can execute the query in the where claus as: `WHERE URL = Ococu`

Please I need your help guys.

Comment: What database do you use? What is the type of variable you insert to the database?

Comment: MySql, I just send a String to the database, for example: Turkish.

Comment: Does the character set in your database set to the relevant one(Turkish)?

Comment: @Ghost93 No it changes the special characters to: &#252; and things like that...

Comment: Try this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444004/mysql-turkish-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell how to fix this problem without knowing the way your columns are declared in your MySQL table, and how your entities (characters) are stored.  This kind of multinational stuff is easiest to handle if your columns are declared something like this:

```
  Title VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci
```

This allows the table to contain your Turkish characters (and Greek and Hungarian, for that matter) without having to be entity-coded (`&#252;`, etc.)

If in fact your tables are coded this way, try the following SELECT statement:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM Article
  WHERE Title = 'ococu' 
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Being ignorant of Turkish, I don't know the reasons for this, but it's clear that the Turkish collation treats `ö` as a different letter from `o`, likewise for `ç` and `c`, and `ü` and `u`. However, the utf_general_ci collation treats those letters as the same. That's why the `SELECT` statement above works.

IF your data in the table is stored entity-coded (`&#252;`, etc.) you really ought to translate it to utf8 so you can use this kind of search.

Finally, the fragment of URL you're mentioning with the value `ococu` is often called a *slug* in the trade. Your title `Öçöçü` needs to be converted to the slug value for searching.  My suggestion above employs the collation to do that. It's worth mentioning that content management systems often store an article's title and slug in separate columns in the database table. This allows the creation of the slug from the title to be done explicitly at the time the article is created.

Here's a Stack Overflow item explaining how to use C# to turn a unicode phrase into a slug.

[URL Slugify algorithm in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920744/url-slugify-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I created 2 columns, one for the title with the foreign characters, and the other for the slug (this is used as the URL), is this a good solution too (like you mentioned)?

Comment: Yes, the two-column approach will be high-quality and scale up easily.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to have 2 separate fields in the DB, one for title, another for url available. Sometimes you would want to have the title changed, but url intact, so the already existing links are not broken. And you probably would not want to have spaces and other special characters in your url, so you'd want to shorten and replace symbols (just as you describe in your question).

Also this mitigates some of the security risks that can be exposed, if third party create articles on your site, like executing nasty scripts from url parameter.

Comment: How should webprogrammers fix this? Should they also create 2 seperate fields?

Comment: I'd say the url handle should be generated from title automatically - replace spaces with `-`, remove special characters and cut the long string. This is not for a user to input, so no extra field on the input form, but extra field in DB table.

Comment: Yea, I was also thinking about this, but I didn't know if there were other better options