# Turkish character issue while inserting into MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation

I have trouble with inserting strings that includes Turkish characters. I am trying to insert "öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ" as string.

I put the line indicated below into the head of php file:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1254");
```

I get data from ajax with (although it is not important, I write it)

```
$json = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
```

Here is insert command:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('" . $user->get_name() . "')";
```

Now, I tried two cases of assigning values to variables:

CASE 1

1. **php:** $name = $json['name'];
2. **browser:** Ã¶Ã§ÅŸÄ±ÄŸÃ¼Ã–Ã‡ÅÄ°ÄÃœ
3. **database:** Ã§ÅŸÄ±ÄŸÃ¼Ã–Ã‡ÅžÄ°ÄžÃœ

CASE 2

1. **php:** $name = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9", $json['name']);
2. **browser:** öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ
3. **database:** çþýðüÖÇÞÝÐÜ

"1" is my assigning type of string, "2" is the result of "echo $user->get_name();" depending on the assignment at "1", and "3" is the value in database cell. I can get true result in "echo" in CASE 2, but corrupted result is inserted into database. My DB collation is: "utf8_turkish_ci".

(Php 5.4.17, MySQL 5.6.13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem sounds like you've missed to specify a character encoding somewhere. to solve this, simply make sure you've set character encoding to **utf-8 everywere** (it doesn't actually need to be utf-8, just *the same* everywhere - but if you've messed up something and need to change some places anyway, i'd strongly recommend using utf-8):

- tell MySQL to use utf-8. to do this, add this to your my.cnf:

  > ```
  > collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
  > character_set_server = utf8
  > ```
- before interacting with mysql, send this two querys:

  > ```
  > SET NAMES 'utf8';
  > CHARSET 'utf8';
  > ```

  or, alternatively, let php do this afteropening the connection:

  > ```
  > mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
  > ```
- set UTF-8 as the default charset for your database

  > ```
  > CREATE DATABASE `my_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
  > ```
- do the same for tables:

  > ```
  > CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  >   -- ...
  > ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  > ```
- assuming the client is a browser, serve your content as utf-8 and the the correct header:

  > ```
  > header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  > ```

  to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  > ```
- and, last but not least, tell the browser to submit forms using utf-8

  > ```
  > <form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
  > ```

Or check here smiler question . [MYSQL - Turkish character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444004/mysql-turkish-character/10444230#10444230)

Answer (score 2):

If you use utf-8 this problem doesn't occur.

My suggestion is convert encoding to utf8.

Answer (score 1):

I think you used utf 8, please try

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in mysql part you must use

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

example php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />   
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
            mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");   
            $sql = "select name from users";
            //........
            //........
            //echo "abc";           
    ?>    

    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: this solution inserted null into db. on the other hand, echo gives "?" question marks instead of each character.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the MySQL query before any queries to this table:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8_turkish_ci' / SET NAMES 'ISO-8859-9'
```

or

```
$params = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'ISO-8859-9\'',
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd, $params];
```

Don't use iconv for that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by only

- removing iconv() conversions
- replacing previous header with "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');" as indicated above by other members.

thanks a lot.