# How to fix missing turkish characters using UTF-8 without bom?

Tags: php

I have an interesting problem;
I create an image with php and my header is like this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png;');
```

While i am creating image i get information from my database and i create image regarding those informations.

so far so good but here is the issue;
the contents which i get from my database include turkish characters but browser cannot display them.

If i encode the php file as a utf-8, it gives an "headers already sent" error.
On the other hand, if i encode the php file  utf-8 without bom, to get rid of the error mentioned above, it does not give any error but turkish characters doesn't appear well again.

I appreciate your helps.

example:
http://sjdijital.com/lolcaps/pages/capsyeni.php?pId=7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444004/mysql-turkish-character

Comment: guys, thanks i solved my problem by doing this:

i am not showing the image from php instead of this i am saving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to display the image online which created with imagecopy, some problems could be occured such as your question(font issues) if you do not save it, instead of that first save the created image and then display the saved image.